# Android GraphView with gradient background

Tags: java, android, material-design, android-xml, mpandroidchart

I'm using the [MPChart Library for Android](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) to create graphs. I want to create an effect similar to the graph in the picture below.[image: graph]

The result that I'm getting, however, is this: [image: graph]

What I want is for the gradient to fade away quickly rather than covering the full height of the graph, in order to achieve the desired result.

Here's my code where I set the background of the graph:

```
if (Utils.getSDKInt() >= 18) {
        Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.graph_gradient);
        dataSet.setFillDrawable(drawable);
    }
```

**graph_gradient.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:endColor="@color/graphColorFill"
        android:centerColor="@color/graphColorFillCenter"
        android:startColor="@android:color/transparent" />
</shape>
```

**Colors:**

```
<color name="graphColorFill">#1DE9B6</color>
<color name="graphColorFillCenter">#901DE9B6</color>
```

**Edit**:
If I use @android:color/transparent as the centerColor, I get the following effect, as you can see the fade disappears on the left hand side of the graph (because it is lower down):
[image: graph]

Comment: what about `@android:color/transparent` the centerColor too ?

Comment: @Ibrahim - Good idea, but I tried that earlier - see the edit